# asp.net page closed before response sent

Tags: asp.net

What happens if a long running page is closed by the user before he has received a response?

Does the page continue to run in the it's thread or is the thread terminated as soon as the user closes the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oded is correct, the request keeps processing long after the user has browsed away or closed their browser window. For fun try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < 100; count++)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Processing {0}, IsClientConnected={1}", count, Response.IsClientConnected);
        Response.Write(string.Format("Processing {0}<br/>", count));
        Response.Flush();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    Response.Write("<h1>Done<h1/>");
}
```

The request keeps processing after navigating away, but the [IsClientConnected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.isclientconnected.aspx) property changes to false. You *can* use this to your advantage, but you have to write code to take advantage of that, normally for long running requests.

```
Processing 0, IsClientConnected=True
Processing 1, IsClientConnected=True
Processing 2, IsClientConnected=True
Processing 3, IsClientConnected=True
Processing 4, IsClientConnected=True
Processing 5, IsClientConnected=True
Processing 6, IsClientConnected=True
Processing 7, IsClientConnected=True
Processing 8, IsClientConnected=True
Processing 9, IsClientConnected=True
Processing 10, IsClientConnected=True
Processing 11, IsClientConnected=True
Processing 12, IsClientConnected=True
Processing 13, IsClientConnected=False
Processing 14, IsClientConnected=False
Processing 15, IsClientConnected=False
Processing 16, IsClientConnected=False
Processing 17, IsClientConnected=False
```

Comment: the IsClientConnected property is actually what I need, I can stop the execution once this property becomes false. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The page will continue to execute - the server has no way of telling that the browser is no longer there. One of the consequences of [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) being stateless.

Comment: I thought that once the user closes the page the TCP connection is closed too, and the server detects that and closes the thread.

Comment: @diamandiev - I don't believe so, I don't think [keep-alive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) works that way. It isn't difficult to test (using `Thread.Sleep`)

Comment: @oded in my log I have see that an exception is throw with the message that the user terminate the connection and the page stopped. I do not find right now, but I get them time to time.

Comment: Error :System.Web.HttpException (0x80070057): The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80070057.
at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)
at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()
at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush)
at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush()
at .ProcessRequest_inside(HttpContext context)
at .ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) (and all that is not done by my program )

Comment: @Aristos - Are you sure this is not something coming from the use of `WebClient` or similar?

Comment: See this for an explanation of that error:  http://blog.whitesites.com/fixing-The-remote-host-closed-the-connection-The-error-code-is-0x80070057__633882307305519259_blog.htm    At any rate, @Oded is  right.   http is purely a stateless protocol.  The code consinues executing, unless it encounters an error.

Comment: @oded I do not know what creates this message, is really rare. Usually is as you say, but time to time I get the error on my logs.

Comment: @Aristos - See the comment from DavidStratton - it happens when users click through before viewstate fully loaded.

Comment: @oded this page that gets the log is with out view state, and with out links. There is the rare case the the user just terminate with the hard way the connection. Anyway +1 is as you say, just some rare cases.